# IF i removed "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" in my MVC 4 application then what will happened?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

IF i removed "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" in my MVC 4 application then what will happened?
We are custom validation instead of MVC validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That file handles the ajax interaction for the Ajax helpers in MVC

So things like Ajax.ActionLink, Ajax.BeginForm would stop working.

If you aren't using them, then it is no issue, if you are, leave it in.

Comment: We are using MVC4 and in webconfig we have key     <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />. Even after removing "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" file from master still ajax.beginform is working in our view pages

Comment: Make sure that you have removed the non mim version too for a good test.  also, it doesn't stop the form posting back, it just won't post back via ajax, it will do a full postback instead